# CGI on IIS8, Program Hanging

Tags: iis, web, cgi

I have read several articles on how to enable CGI use on my IIS8 server. I have configured ISAPI and CGI Restrictions to allow unspecified CGI modules and set the CGI to execute permissions. When I try to invoke the program through the website it just hangs there loading and never does anything.

Comment: in other words it is timing out after 15 minutes, this program was tested on a whole different server and worked fine so I know it's not the program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forgotten to add the couple of %s at the end of CGI executable:

perl.exe "%s" %s